# How to disable USB Autosuspend

Tags: usb

i'm trying out Xubuntu 12.04, preference was due to hardware specifications of my machine. My problem is my broadband connection using a USB Huawei modem and Sun Telecoms Philippines keeps getting disconnected.

I've read in Ubuntu forums that this may be due to the USB Autosuspend. How can USB Autosuspend be disabled?

I'm not using powernap or powertop, is there a way i can disable usb autosuspend from the terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable auto power off of usb devices like usb mouse?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse)

Comment: How about setting the auto-suspend threshold time for your specific device to a very high amount - as described by [this forum thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130915/optical-mouse-temporarily-turns-off-when-system-is-idle)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable usb-autosuspend for a specific device?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device)